# Importing pandas shows ImportError: cannot import name hashtable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have installed pandas on python 3.3, and coded like this:

```
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame

csvdata = pandas.read_csv('datafile.csv')
df = DataFrame(csvdata)
```

It comes with the following error message:

```
cannot import name hashtable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\document\test4.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to solve this error?  Python and pandas were successfully installed.

Comment: Pandas was not installed correctly it seems

Comment: I get the same error in WinPython (py3.4) _sometimes_.

Answer (score 27):

#### Update: I now recommend installing the scientific python stack using [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/).

Pandas comes bundled and can easily be updated using conda:

```
conda update pandas
```

It also comes bundled with cython, scipy (which is tricky to install via pip), statsmodels, and manages the dependencies/reationships between these packages for you.

*It's worth emphaising that you don't need admin/sudo access to install it on the machine to install Anaconda.*

---

If you're not using Anaconda, the recommended way to [install pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#overview) is via pip (on Mac and Windows):

```
pip install pandas
```

*On Linux you can also install with `python-pandas` in whichever repository, but be aware you may be installing an older version of pandas, ideally you should be using the latest stable version.*

---

It looks like you have tried to [install from source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#installing-from-source), about which the docs mention:

> Installing from the git repository **requires a recent installation of Cython as the cythonized C sources are no longer checked into source control**. Released source distributions will contain the built C files. I recommend installing the latest Cython via `easy_install -U Cython`
>
> Note that **you will not be able to import pandas** if you open an interpreter in the source directory **unless you build the C extensions in place**:
>
> ```
> python setup.py build_ext --inplace
> ```

*Without compiling [`hashtables.pyx`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/master/pandas) (and a few other cython files), pandas is unable to import them. These are required for pandas (which explains your error message).*

*Note: this [error message has been made more descriptive for 0.11.1 onwards](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3827), it will say that the C-extensions were not built.*

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Andy.  Honestly, I don't know where to start with your suggestion of "pip install pandas".  Where and what application do I have to run with the text?  Since I just started learning Python, I may need detailed/step-wise instruction.  Please let me know how to.  Thanks,

Comment: @sky404 have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)? Hope it can help!

Comment: I did install using pip, but still get the same error. I'm running a small web server using python and want to use pandas. The error will appear on my webpage. If I try "import pandas" from a local python prompt, I will get a different error: SyntaxError: future feature unicode_literals is not defined

Comment: Not sure if this would be useful for anyone, but using easy_install -U Cython instead of pip install Cython allowed me to install from source on Win 8.1 64

Comment: I get this error message for `pip install pandas` on linux (fedora 20).

Comment: @hobs it may be preferable to install pandas via the fedora package https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/python-pandas/. I now recommend using conda (much easier for the python data stack).

Answer (score 4):

I have already tried all the stuff above, didn't work for me.

You can just change your version of `pandas` by

```
pip install --user pandas==0.22
```

only this worked for me:)

Answer (score 3):

The pandas Python 3.3 binary here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ seems to have not been compiled successfully. I haven't had the time to configure my build machine to build and test Python 3.3 binaries but I do know that things work on Python 3.3 on the other platforms.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem too when I tried installing pandas 0.13.1. It installed but I could not import it.

As  @danioyuan suggests, I installed Cython using easy_install and now I am able to import pandas.

Comment: or just `apt-get install cython`

Comment: Yes, both ways works. But I amnnot sure why I got a down-vote for that :-/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
I installed pandas using command pip install pandas.

By default, my pip installed pandas in dist-packages of python3.2 and my default python version was 2.7.
As a result when I did python to open the interactive shell and try to do

```
 import pandas

 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
 from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
 ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
```

What solved my problem was:

```
 python3.2
 import pandas
```

Please check that the you use the same Python version whose dist-packages contain pandas.