# Pandas installation on Mac OS X: ImportError (cannot import name hashtable)

Tags: python, hashtable, pandas, cython, importerror

I would like to build pandas from source rather than use a package manager because I am interested in contributing. **The first time** I tried to build pandas, these were the steps I took:

1) created the virtualenv
`mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages pandas`

2) activated the virtualenv

3) installed Anaconda CE. However, this was installed in ~/anaconda.

4) cloned pandas

5) built C extensions in place

`(pandas)ems ~/.virtualenvs/pandas/localrepo/pandas> ~/anaconda/bin/python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

6) built pandas

`(pandas)ems ~/.virtualenvs/pandas/localrepo/pandas> ~/anaconda/bin/python setup.py build`

7) ran nosetests on master branch

Tests failed:
(pandas)ems ~/.virtualenvs/pandas/localrepo/pandas> nosetests pandas
    E
    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: ValueError (numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/EmilyChen/.virtualenvs/pandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py",     line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
    File "/Users/EmilyChen/.virtualenvs/pandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
    File "/Users/EmilyChen/.virtualenvs/pandas/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
    File "/Users/EmilyChen/.virtualenvs/pandas/localrepo/pandas/pandas/**init**.py", line 6, in 
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
    File "numpy.pxd", line 156, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:20354)
    ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

---

Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

Someone on the PyData mailing list said:

> It looks like you have NumPy installed someplace else on your machine and AnacondaCE is not playing nicely in the virtualenv. The error you are getting is a Cython error message which occurs when the NumPy version it built against doesn't match the installed version on your system-- I had thought that 1.7.x was supposed to be ABI compatible with 1.6.x (so this would not happen) but I guess not. Sigh

The numpy version in Anaconda CE library is 1.7.0b2 and my system numpy installation is version 1.5.1. Setup.py linked to the numpy in the Anaconda distribution's libraries when it built pandas but my guess is it's linking to my system version when nosetests runs /pandas/**init**.py

**Next**, I repeated the steps outside a virtualenv, but got the same error. **Finally**, I decided to install all the dependencies in a new virtualenv instead of using the Anaconda distribution to build pandas. This way, I can see that dependencies like numpy reside in the lib directory of the virtualenv python installation, which takes precedent when pandas.**init** runs import statements. This is what I did:

1) installed numpy, dateutil, pytz, cython, scipy, matplotlib and openpyxl using pip

2) built c extensions in place

3) pandas install output here: http://pastebin.com/3CKf1f9i

4) pandas did not install correctly

```
(pandas)ems ~/.virtualenvs/pandas/localrepo/pandas> python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
 cannot import name hashtable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
```

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422976/python3-3-importerror-cannot-import-name-hashtable) but cython installed in my case, and I am trying to build successfully from source rather than using pip like the answer recommended..

```
(pandas)ems ~/.virtualenvs/pandas/localrepo/pandas> which cython
/Users/EmilyChen/.virtualenvs/pandas/bin/cython
```

Comment: My first thought is that calling your virtualenv pandas is a bad idea (I've done the same before, and I think it confuses things). The fact hastables has failed definitely means that you haven't built the cython files inplace correctly, I *think* this should be done after building pandas itself, so try running that part again.

Comment: Yep. Somehow I missed this from the docs: 'Note that you will not be able to import pandas if you open an interpreter in the source directory unless you build the C extensions in place' http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've received the same error (`ImportError: cannot import name hashtable`) when trying to import pandas from the source code directory.  Try starting the python interpreter from a different directory and import pandas again.

Comment: Your suggestion worked: after navigating to a different directory, I was able to import pandas and pass all the tests. Thanks! You and Andy were both right. It seems if I start the interpreter and import pandas while I'm in the pandas source directory, I would need to build the c extensions in place after the pandas build.

Comment: What's the reason it doesn't work on source directory?

Comment: yes, even if I didn't install pandas from source (install through apt-get), I was unable to import pandas because I was on the same directory where pandas source was (downloaded before knowing the apt way). But what is the reason it is not working from the source directory?

Comment: In my case the issue was solved by running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` before running nosetests. See also ["Installing from source"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#installing-from-source).

Comment: @Seid.M @lucky1928 the problem likely lies in `python` putting `.` before any additional places to look for its modules. Thus if you happen to be at the top of pandas source tree, it is used first and the installed version is thus ignored.