# imp.load_module pandas issue

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

I'm attempting to use `imp.load_module` to import a file I've created which relies on the `pandas` library. However, when importing the module an exception is thrown:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in 
     from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
    ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
```

The weird thing is that if I examine sys.modules, I can see the module is loaded:

```
{ ...
     'hashtable': <module 'pandas.hashtable' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/hashtable.so'>,
  ...
     'pandas.hashtable': <module 'pandas.hashtable' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/hashtable.so'>,
... }
```

Am I missing something? I'm unsure of what I can do from this point, and I'm wondering if this is somehow related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14568070/435460).

Comment: It looks like that error is raised by pandas itself.  Does doing just `import pandas` work?

Comment: From your `sys.modules`, it looks like you may have put `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/` on your `sys.path` as well as `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` itself. Which can easily cause problems like this. If you don't know, can you dump out `sys.path` and see?

Comment: My file does `import pandas`, so somehow this is within the actual import itself. I have logic to recursively import dependencies, which led me to discover that the `hashtable` module (and also the `tslib` and `lib` modules) was already imported.

Comment: @abarnert it looks like both *are* on my `sys.path`. I'll get it to stop that (use one *or* the other), and then report back on the outcome.

Comment: @JesseBuesking: Definitely eliminate the `dist-packages/pandas` on your path, not the `dist-packages`. You want to use `pandas` as a package, after all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing pandas shows ImportError: cannot import name hashtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422976/importing-pandas-shows-importerror-cannot-import-name-hashtable)

Comment: pandas wasn't built properly, how did you install it?

Comment: @abarnert I've temporarily altered my code to prevent `dist-packages/pandas` from being included on the path, but the issue persists.

Comment: @AndyHayden I spoke with the coworker who did the install, and they did in fact use pip. I think the issue is more-or-less tied to using `imp.load_source` to do the import.