# ipython pandas import error

Tags: pandas, ipython

I am using ipython for the first time. Can't understand what is going wrong here. Can someone point out what is going wrong? Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

### cannot import name hashtable

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py in ()
      5 
      6 try:
----> 7     from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
      8 except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
      9     import sys

ImportError: cannot import name hashtable

Comment: Have you checked the solutions in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568070/pandas-installation-on-mac-os-x-importerror-cannot-import-name-hashtable

Answer (score 0):

are you using anaconda ? if so try to run conda in your terminal to check that it is exported in the path - otherwise try export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH