# python 2.7 module pandas not installing "cannot import name hashtable"

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, hashtable, importerror

I tried looking for an answer to this around the forum/google, but I can't find anything. My issue is this (from python console):

```
>>> import pandas
cannot import name hashtable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: cannot import name hashtable //also can't import name NaT somtimes
```

I ran the windows 1-click installer prior to attempting the import. I'm running everything 32-bit. The pandas installer is for python 2.7.

Here's a list of modules that I have correctly imported into Python.

1. setuptools
2. pip
3. mox
4. dateutil
5. six
6. numpy
7. SQLAlchemy

I'm on windows 7.

I also have anaconda installed, but that was really just a "hail mary" after I tried everything else. My end goal is to install the [ultra-finance module](https://code.google.com/p/ultra-finance/). However, it seems to require pandas, hence me being stuck.

I'm a python noob, so please don't assume I know anything. Thanks.

EDIT: please let me know if I can provide any extra information.

Comment: How did you install pandas? Were you installing from source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python3.3\_ImportError: cannot import name hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422976/python3-3-importerror-cannot-import-name-hashtable) (granted that *says* 3.3, but the issue is the same)

Comment: installed using the installer - pandas-0.11.0.win32-py2.7.exe. I'm pretty sure i also tried source a few hours ago using the disutil method discussed here: http://docs.python.org/2/install/ I'm going to try that one again to make sure i did it right.

Comment: you're right, I'll check that thread. Thanks for the heads up, I'll check that thread and if it helps i'm assuming I should just delete this one?

Comment: I'd leave it so it comes up in google (and other people with the same issue can find it), I've voted to close as a duplicate (that was google redirects). :)

Comment: I really appreciate the help Andy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to [install pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#overview) is via [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html):

```
pip install pandas
```

*This hashtables error arises from the cython files not being [built](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/install.html#installing-from-source). This error message [will be more informative from 0.11.1](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3827).*

Comment: Note: this question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422976/importing-pandas-shows-importerror-cannot-import-name-hashtable), see my longer answer there.

Comment: In fact, the real cause of this error is that some internal dependency of panda is broken, that's why installing or updating via pip solves the problem most of the times.

Comment: @amorales this isn't an internal "dependancy" as much as the internal cython (.pyx) files being compiled/built. Updating via conda and pip should fix as they ship precompiled.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code in Spyder (Anaconda -> Spyder). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have python scripts included in your system path variable. In my case I had to add "C:\Python27\Scripts"

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem when downloading Pandas to my Windows 8 system. The first error I had was an egg error, but after installing some packages I think I have the solution.

First look at the previous pip errors with Pandas, make sure you have the most updated pip.

The second part is downloading wheel using

```
pip install wheel
```

After installing wheel and having the dependencies for panda and using pip it worked correctly.