# Error while importing pandas in python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing pandas on python 2.7. Please help me to figure out the issue

```
  >>> import pandas
        cannot import name NaT
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\_
        _init__.py", line 7, in <module>
            from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
          File "pandas\lib.pyx", line 50, in init pandas.lib (pandas\lib.c:78588)
        ImportError: cannot import name NaT
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python 2.7 module pandas not installing "cannot import name hashtable"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128917/python-2-7-module-pandas-not-installing-cannot-import-name-hashtable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The recommended way to install[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#overview) is via [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html):

```
pip install pandas
```

the problem in your pandas installation is causing this hashtable error.

Comment: $ pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied:pandas in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
Requirement already satisfied:python-dateutil in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):numpy>=1.7.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.9.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas)

Comment: i got this when i used pip install pandas. but now it gives error as:
cannot import name hashtable

Comment: I guess you are trying to import pandas from the source code directory. Try starting the python interpreter from a different directory and import pandas again.