# Broken PyCharm Interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been using PyCharm CE with pretty great success. But I just installed the basemap module (having to compile geos and basemap from source) and it seems to have broken the PyCharm interpreter. All of my modules load properly when I run Python from the terminal, and all of my modules run properly when I run Python from the terminal WITHIN PyCharm, but now when I attempt to load certain packages from the interactive interpreter, I get error messages. For example, now when I try to import pandas in the interactive interpreter, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_code
exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
File "<ipython-input-3-af55e7023913>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
import pandas.core.config_init
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py", line 4, in <module>
from pandas.core.format import detect_console_encoding
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 12, in <module>
from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, _ensure_index
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 10, in <module>
import pandas.index as _index
File "index.pyx", line 34, in init pandas.index (pandas/index.c:14957)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
from pkg_resources import resource_stream
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2717, in <module>
add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources.py", line 682, in subscribe
callback(dist)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2717, in <lambda>
add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2255, in activate
list(map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt')))
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1851, in declare_namespace
path = sys.modules[parent].__path__
KeyError: 'dap'
```

If I try to import pandas again, in the same session, the error message changes to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
cannot import name hashtable
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_code
exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
File "<ipython-input-6-af55e7023913>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
```

What did I do to break the interpreter? I tried reinstalling PyCharm to reset and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Fork 50 bucks/year and get the good stuff with full support from jetbrains. Just saying... :-)

Comment: considering I somehow broke it even worse.... not bad advice

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14428450/1662973

Comment: Does the opened project use Virtualenv? If so, check if you have set correctly your PYTHONPATH for given project.

Answer (score 0):

I case this helps anyone.  I had this issue in a Django project that also was setup to use Google App Engine; therefore, PyCharm loaded the GAE version of many Python packages (they were being added to my PYTHONPATH).  I disabled Google App Engine support in File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Google App Engine.  The problem went away.

Note: I did not have the Pandas import issue when running my Django app outside of PyCharm.