# Update Pandas - cannot import name 'hashtable'

Tags: python, pandas

I've update to pandas version v0.15.1 via anaconda (cmd -> conda update pandas) - using python 3.4. Now when I try to import pandas the following error appears "ImportError: cannot import name 'hashtable'
". Anyone an idea how to solve the error? Thank you.

Comment: This question might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422976/importing-pandas-shows-importerror-cannot-import-name-hashtable

Comment: I have tried to follow what has been suggested but I cannot solve my issue. I installed cython as someone suggested but still nothing and it has been working all the time without any issues. I simply updated pandas and then the issue was there.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading back to your previous `pandas` version and see if the problem persists? The answer in the linked question suggests that you should not encounter this problem if you are in a `conda` environment. Did you make sure that the interpreter you are using is indeed from your conda virtualenv?

Comment: I have just downgraded to v0.14.1 and works again. However, I upgraded because I need something from v0.15.1

Comment: that is indeed interesting. I am currently using `0.15.1` on python3.3 on OSX and I don't see any issues. You may want to post a bug report at `conda`'s bugtracker at github and include your `OS` and python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Spyder and other Python processes and try

```
conda install -f pandas
```

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/256