# Development build of pandas giving importerror: C extension: 'hashtable' not built on python 3.4 (anaconda)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Try to do a development build with 3.4 (have previously managed in 2.7). Python is just an anaconda installation on osx10.10. I can get

I:

- git cloned pandas
- ran python setup.py build_ext --inplace (got no errors)
- ran python setup.py develop.

But when I try and import pandas I get:

```
import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-af55e7023913>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd

  File "/Users/Nick/github/pandas/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))

ImportError: C extension: 'hashtable' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Note that when I do build_ext I get the following (apparently fine) output:

```
pandas(master)$python setup.py build_ext --inplace

running build_ext
skipping 'pandas/index.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/lib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/parser.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/src/period.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/hashtable.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/algos.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/tslib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/src/sparse.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/src/testing.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/msgpack.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
```

Further, I can get pandas installed if I run `conda install pandas`, but would really like a development environment for code development.

[Similar to this, which looked unsolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761152/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331344/update-pandas-cannot-import-name-hashtable)

Comment: Have you tried `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`?

Comment: @chrisb you are my hero. Thanks! post as an answer and I'll select.

Comment: A small note here: Why do you install `pandas` via `setup.py` instead of using `conda`? The really cool thing about anaconda is that it ships already compiled versions of various packages of the stack of scientific software. So when using `conda install` you should never run into these kind of issues.

Comment: @cel that's great if you just want to _use_ a package, but if you want to modify the package (add features, etc.), a pre-compiled package isn't very useful. When you make a development build, python automatically integrates any changes the user (me) has made to the package code every time it imports. This makes it easy to test new code.

Comment: pls read the contributing docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html); generally it is useful to use conda to create your build environment itself; the reason you need --force is that you have another process open with Python

Comment: ah, ok, thanks @Jeff.

Comment: I have the same problem with python 3.3.2. I tried the flags above, but I keep getting the same `ImportError`. I install from source because I am a user on a hpc cluster and i don't have administrative rights

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer, due to @chrisb in comments, was to run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`.

Comment: I have the same problem as you did. Where exactly should I run this code `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`? I tried to run this in the pandas folder but it didn't find `setup.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it reinstalling pandas with this command:

```
conda install pandas
```

Everything was working fine, but I installed something using pip and started having problems. This solved it.