# Pandas development workflow: conda and building C extensions

Tags: python, pandas, conda

I'm currently writing some code for the Pandas core and I'm wondering if my workflow is correct.

As the Travis CI instance tests against different versions of Python, I have conda set up to switch between the different versions locally so I can see if the test suite passes or fails.

But every time I switch between environments I get:

```
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (C extension: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.)
```

and when I do `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` I get:

```
/home/some_user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-17.1.1-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py:294: UserWarning: The version specified ('0.16.2-134-g84d6eba') is an invalid version, this may not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI. Please see PEP 440 for more details.
running build_ext
skipping 'pandas/index.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/src/period.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/algos.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/lib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/tslib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/parser.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/hashtable.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/src/sparse.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/src/testing.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pandas/msgpack.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
```

So, as per @Jeff's comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495657/development-build-of-pandas-giving-importerror-c-extension-hashtable-not-bui), I rebuild the extensions using:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force
```

And things work fine. But the build takes a good few minutes to run, and it feels like I'm doing something wrong. (It certainly doesn't mention having to force a rebuild in the [Contributing to Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html) guide.

So am I doing something wrong, or is this just the way it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot build multiple versions in the same space. You need to do one of these:

- put the cloned directory inside of the `conda` directory itself. E.g. if you have `pandas2.6`, then you can (your path may vary if you have miniconda/anaconda installed), to `~/minicona/envs/pandas2.6` then clone `pandas` there and `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and access locally
- use `python setup.py build`. If your clone directory is `~/pandas`. This puts the builds for different versions in `~/pandas/builds/.....`. The downside of this is you actually have to path things to run them, e.g. `nosetests ~/pandas/builds/....../pandas/tests/test_series.py` for example. Further you to rebuild each time you want to make a change (but since the c-extensions are already built this is usually very fast).

Comment: Wonderful stuff. Thanks. Might be worth putting some of this in the developer's guide.

Comment: actually I should add, that you can do ``conda develop conda.receipe`` and it will create a develop link (in the env)

Comment: Sure! When I get to grips with this, I'll PR some notes into the guide.