# how to sort dataframe based on particular (string)columns using python pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas data frame contains the following data:

```
product,values
 a1,     10
 a5,     20
 a10,    15
 a2,     45
 a3,     12
 a6,     67
```

I have to sort this data frame based on the product column. Thus, I would like to get the following output:

```
product,values
 a10,     15
 a6,      67
 a5,      20
 a3,      12
 a2,      45
 a1,      10
```

Unfortunately, I'm facing the following error:

> ErrorDuringImport(path, sys.exc_info())
>
> ErrorDuringImport: problem in views - type 'exceptions.Indentation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can first [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) `digits` and cast to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html). Then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) of column `sort` and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) this column:

```
df['sort'] = df['product'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
df.sort_values('sort',inplace=True, ascending=False)
df = df.drop('sort', axis=1)
print (df)
  product  values
2     a10      15
5      a6      67
1      a5      20
4      a3      12
3      a2      45
0      a1      10
```

It is necessary, because if use only [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.sort_values('product',inplace=True, ascending=False)
print (df)
  product  values
5      a6      67
1      a5      20
4      a3      12
3      a2      45
2     a10      15
0      a1      10
```

Another idea is use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) library:

```
from natsort import index_natsorted, order_by_index

df = df.reindex(index=order_by_index(df.index, index_natsorted(df['product'], reverse=True)))
print (df)
  product  values
2     a10      15
5      a6      67
1      a5      20
4      a3      12
3      a2      45
0      a1      10
```

Comment: i m using python 2.7 version

Comment: I think copy text of error, under tags  in question give `edit` and paste text under text of question. Thanks.

Comment: k now i will add that

Comment: It looks like your `pandas` is broken - see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14422976/2901002).

Comment: what i have do now?

Comment: Do you use anaconda?

Comment: and python 2.7 version

Comment: give me one solution

Comment: maybe help try update pandas - if use `windows` -  in `command line` use `conda update pandas`

Comment: i m not able to do that..because that anoconda inbuilt in our product

Comment: phoooo, so it is bigger problem. One idea - maybe if use lower version of pandas, try remove `, expand=False` from first row of code. What is version of pandas? `print pd.versions()`

Comment: hm k...i will try that

Comment: Super Ia am glad it working. Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too.

Comment: how to add d in all rows?

Comment: i mean my column contains 1,2,3,4,5 but i have to change d1,d2,d3,d4,d5

Comment: use list comprehension - `df.columns = ['d' + str(col) for col in df.columns]`

Comment: What if the column is the index column and has not column name?

Comment: @Toonia - Can you be more specific?

Comment: @jezreal In your example, 'product' was a column name and you could do df['product']. Imagine the product column is the index column but contains the strings which you want to sort. Something like df[df.index] but doesn't work.

Comment: @Toonia - so need `df.index` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, need to sort `df` according to the entries of `df.index` which are strings with numbers in them

Comment: @Toonia - so use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580978/naturally-sorting-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "product": ['a1,', 'a5,', 'a10,', 'a2,','a3,','a6,'],
   "value": [10, 20, 15, 45, 12, 67]
})
df
==>
  product   value
0   a1,      10
1   a5,      20
2   a10,     15
3   a2,      45
4   a3,      12
5   a6,      67


df.sort_values(by='product', key=lambda col: col.str[1:-1].astype(int), ascending=False)
==>
  product   value
2   a10,     15
5   a6,      67
1   a5,      20
4   a3,      12
3   a2,      45
0   a1,      10
```