# how to aggregate data in Y axis and plot a line graph in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have data as below. I want to plot a simple line graph in python where item on the X axis and total sales in the Y axis. Total sales is the aggregated sales at the item level.

Can anyone help on this?

```
Item    Date    Sales
Item1   4/25/2018   55
Item2   4/25/2018   21
Item3   4/25/2018   50
Item4   4/25/2018   58
Item5   4/25/2018   81
Item6   4/25/2018   79
Item7   4/25/2018   61
Item8   4/25/2018   37
Item9   4/25/2018   51
Item10  4/25/2018   53
Item1   4/26/2018   27
Item2   4/26/2018   28
Item3   4/26/2018   26
Item4   4/26/2018   95
Item5   4/26/2018   15
Item6   4/26/2018   89
Item7   4/26/2018   42
Item8   4/26/2018   21
Item9   4/26/2018   39
Item10  4/26/2018   67
Item1   4/27/2018   14
Item2   4/27/2018   45
Item3   4/27/2018   35
Item4   4/27/2018   68
Item5   4/27/2018   76
Item6   4/27/2018   63
Item7   4/27/2018   73
Item8   4/27/2018   61
Item9   4/27/2018   59
Item10  4/27/2018   93
Item1   4/28/2018   27
Item2   4/28/2018   63
Item3   4/28/2018   55
Item4   4/28/2018   73
Item5   4/28/2018   58
Item6   4/28/2018   90
Item7   4/28/2018   67
Item8   4/28/2018   72
Item9   4/28/2018   64
Item10  4/28/2018   98
```

Regards,
philip

Comment: You should consider using pandas for this task. Date vs item columns. Then sum all items per day in another column. Then plot each column vs date. If this is a one-off task, you will be faster using Excel/LibreOfficeCalc.

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas, this would be achieved by loading the data into a dataframe, doing a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and adding the values of sales per group. Eventually, pandas has wrapped some usual matplotlib plots which can be called directly from pandas.

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # For the desired plot it is not necessary but
                                          # it is a good idea, and allow plots by date too 
df.groupby(by='Item').sum().plot.bar(y='Sales',color='g')
```

Which generates the following plot:

[image]

In order to sort items from 1 to 10 according to the digit, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37693650/2504700) can be used before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

df_grp = df.groupby('Item')['Sales'].sum()
df_grp = df_grp[df_grp.index.str.split('Item').str[1].astype(int).argsort()]
df_grp.plot()
plt.xticks(np.arange(df_grp.shape[0]), df_grp.index, rotation=90)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of doing it without pandas, only with numpy. Strating from an array `items` containing the info on the Item column and `sales` for sale, the code would look like:

```
u, f = np.unique(items, return_inverse=True) # returns unique array of occurences and the indices to retrieve the original items array.
# i.e. u, f = np.unique([1,2,3,1,1,2,1], return_inverse=True) returns
# u: [1,2,3]
# f: [0 1 2 0 0 1 0] such that u[f]==[1,2,3,1,1,2,1]
imgs = np.bincount(f, sales) 
inds = np.argsort(np.char.lstrip(u,'Item').astype(int))
plt.plot(np.arange(len(u)),imgs[inds])
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(u)),u[inds])
```

Note: the input arrays are assumed to have the propper dtype, if this was not the case, then they should be casted into the correct dtype with `.astype()`