# unable to import pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I installed some backtesting libraries which updated pandas version.

Since then I'm getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'hashtable'`

I referred the existing question: [Hashtable Error in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422976/importing-pandas-shows-importerror-cannot-import-name-hashtable).

And tried

```
> pip install pandas

> conda update pandas
```

but nothing seems working. Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT** :

I removed pandas from conda using  `conda remove --force pandas`
And reinstalled it. 
Now I'm getting new error

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'
```

Thanks

Comment: what version of pandas has been installed and what version of python/conda is being used?

Comment: You probably need to install with `pip3`.

Comment: Can you add the whole traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `pandas` from `lib/site-packages` and reinstalled pandas using
`pip install pandas`. It worked.